# Difference in difference - everyone treated and measure different response?

Tags: causality, difference-in-difference

I was wondering if there is a model or study where everyone receives the treatment and measures how post-treatment outcome is different.

For instance, in a state, minimum wage rose and estimate whether the reaction (e.g. employment level) is different by gender or race.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

You are more than free to conduct a pre- versus post-treatment analysis and assess differences in individual responses to your exposure of interest. To be clear, you're well outside the realm of conducting a difference-in-differences analysis. I'm not sure if this was the purpose of your question, but your tag said otherwise. If causality is what you're interested in, then try grabbing some data from a neighboring jurisdiction where the minimum wage remained constant throughout the observation period (i.e., before *and* after your treatment/exposure of interest).

Assessing how individuals within particular employment sectors respond to a shift in wages is perfectly fine. But beware, as your exposure (i.e., shock) is specific to one jurisdiction—only. Any observed differences in employment trends in response to the wage increase might have happened anyway—even in the absence of treatment. Without a subset of non-adopter states/regions, you cannot estimate a counterfactual.

If your only purpose is to investigate differences in employment levels across race or gender in one jurisdiction, then go for it. Interpreting your findings causally is tenuous at best.